# Simple onload event not firing?

Tags: javascript, html

Just made a basic program to fin the root of my problem and I can't seem to find why this is not working at all.

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="carjava.js"></script>
    </head>
<body onload="hi()">
    hi
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
function hi() {
alert("hi");
}
```

I want an alert to pop up when the page loads but nothing happens, any ideas?

Comment: Wow I should have known because I've done it before but another function I didn't even think about was messed up thus stopping the functionality of the rest of the document of the script. Thanks for your time, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why it isn't firing, but this should work:

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="carjava.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        hi
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function hi() {
    alert("hi");
}

window.onload = hi;
```

Answer (score -1):

following code is working fine for me:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="carjava.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function hi()
          {
             alert('hi');
          }
        </script>
    </head>
<body onload="hi()">
    hi
</body>

</html>
```

Its working fine in Firefox & Chrome. Must be something with js file.

Comment: Saying that something is wrong with the JS and not providing a solution is not useful. Instead, try offering your working JS if it differs from the question's.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy if you read the comment, he did have issue with js file.